# Detect silence during recording mac os x sdk

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-audio, audio-recording

I have been struggling to detect silence during recording.

I am successful in recording and playing recorded audio, but getting no idea for silence detection.

For recording, I had used : https://github.com/darcyliu/CocoaSampleCode/tree/master/AVCaptureToAudioUnitOSX 
which works on core audio api.

Any help would be a boon for me.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You can use `AVAudioRecorder` but that's not a perfect way to solve your problem.

```
NSDictionary *settings =@{AVSampleRateKey:@(22050.0),
                          AVFormatIDKey:@(kAudioFormatLinearPCM),
                          AVNumberOfChannelsKey:@(1),
                          AVEncoderAudioQualityKey:@(AVAudioQualityMax),
                          AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey:@(32), 
                          AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey:@(NO), 
                          AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey:@(NO)};
AVAudioRecorder *recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/dev/null"] settings:setting error:nil];
[recorder prepareToRecord];
[recorder setMeteringEnabled:YES];
[recorder record];
NSTimer *levelTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.3f target:self selector:@selector(levelTimerCallback:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Then in `levelTimerCallback:` method

```
[recorder updateMeters];
CGFloat peak = [recorder peakPowerForChannel:0]
CGFloat average = [recorder averagePowerForChannel:0];
```